# Python's `if` statement behave differently depend on where to execute it?

Tags: python

**Why the code `if line and not line[0].isdigit() and line != '\n':` behaves differently while in and out of the project?**
I have the following code extract from my project [meltsubtitles](https://github.com/Celthi/meltSubtitles/blob/master/main.py) in line 88:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as finput:
    for line in finput:
        if line and not line[0].isdigit() and line != '\n':
            pass
        else:
            print(line)
```

when I extract the code out of project and run it with `text.txt`, print out:

```
1

00:00:03,940 --> 00:00:07,550



2

00:00:09,280 --> 00:00:10,650
```

but when I put a similar code to my project, the first `line '1\n'` is not printed. The output is:

```
00:00:03,940 --> 00:00:07,550

2
00:00:09,280 --> 00:00:10,650
```

What I expect is :

```
1
00:00:03,940 --> 00:00:07,550

2
00:00:09,280 --> 00:00:10,650
```

when `line = '1\n'`, I have used pycharm to debug and step into the critical line `if line and not line[0].isdigit() and line != '\n':`, it **strangely** run into the `if` statement while **it shouldn't**,, but when I extract the code, it won't run into `if` statement.

The `test.txt` file is

```
1
00:00:03,940 --> 00:00:07,550
Horsin' Around is filmed before a live studio audience.

2
00:00:09,280 --> 00:00:10,650
Mondays.
```

My project is in github [meltsubtitles](https://github.com/Celthi/meltSubtitles/blob/master/main.py) line 88. 
I'm running Python 3.5 and in win 10.

Answer (score 0):

What's your means about **Similar** code?

I rewrite the task by codes:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def begin_numebr(string=None):
    if string is None:
        return False
    else:
        return string.strip() != '' and string[0].isdigit()

def line_filter(lines):
    return filter(lambda line: begin_numebr(line), lines)

for line in line_filter(open('test.txt')):
    print(line)

def test():
    assert(begin_numebr('')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr(' ')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr('\n')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr('\t')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr('\b')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr()==False)
    assert(begin_numebr('not digit')==False)
    assert(begin_numebr('00not digit')==True)
    print('test done')

    lines = ['001', 'this is']
    logging.debug(line_filter(lines))
    assert(line_filter(lines) == ['001'])

#test()
```